# How to pass a constant to onClick listener in android data binding

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding

I am just getting into the android MVVM. In my project, I have 3 TextViews that will work as a radio group.

[image]

In the above image, any of the options will be selected at a time.

The XML for this is

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.builders.aimsfinance.ui.common.newcandidate.NewCandidateViewModel" />
</data>
   **** Some XML *****
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/candidateSite"
            android:text="Site"
            android:onClick="@{()-> viewModel.setCandidateType()}"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
            android:background="@drawable/big_rounded_rectangle"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_700"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/candidateShop"
            android:text="Shop"
            android:onClick="@{()-> viewModel.setCandidateType()}"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
            android:background="@drawable/big_rounded_rectangle"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_700"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/candidateEmployee"
            android:text="Employee"
            android:onClick="@{()-> viewModel.setCandidateType()}"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
            android:background="@drawable/big_rounded_rectangle"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_700"/>

   **** Some XML *****
```

and in my ViewModel, I have implemented the following function

```
class NewCandidateViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    var typ = MutableLiveData<Int>()

    fun setCandidateType(type: Int) {
        typ.value = type
    }
}
```

Here I set a common handler function `viewModel.setCandidateType()` for all the TextViews and I have to pass a specific integer on clicking each TextViews. Passing hardcoded value like `viewModel.setCandidateType(1)` is working fine. But I don't think this is a proper solution.

My doubt is, how to pass this type of custom values to this handler function from the XML? What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In View:

```
mViewModel.onSelectTypeEvent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, EventObserver {
    when(it) {
        // some event
    }
})
```

In ViewModel:

```
private val _onSelectTypeEvent = MutableLiveData<Event<Int>>()
val onSelectTypeEvent: LiveData<Event<Int>> = _onSelectTypeEvent

fun onSiteClick() {
    _onSelectTypeEvent.value = Event(TYPE_SITE)
}

fun onShopClick() {
    _onSelectTypeEvent.value = Event(TYPE_SHOP)
}

fun onEmployeeClick() {
    _onSelectTypeEvent.value = Event(TYPE_EMPLOYEE)
}

companion object {
    const val TYPE_SITE = 1
    const val TYPE_SHOP = 2
    const val TYPE_EMPLOYEE = 3
}
```

Comment: which Event class I have to use?, can you add that part also, I am new in MVVM

Comment: If there is no data to be passed, it is recommended that you use Event <Unit>, otherwise, you can decide which data type to use according to your needs.